# Pandas dataframe how to groupby bins of numerical column and then count other binary column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe:

```
c1 c2  SED f
1  2   0.2 1
3  3   0.7 1
3  1   0.1 0
8  1   0.6 0
9  2   1   1
4  9   8.3 1
```

I want to group `SED` to bins of width 0.5 and foreach bin, count the number of rows the column `f` is 1 and the number of rows it is 0.

So for this example I will get:

```
SED_bin   cou_0   cou_1     
  0-0.5     1       1
  0.5-1     1       2
  8-8.5     0       1
```

What is the best way to do it?
Please note this is just an example of SED values and there could be more below to above this range so I need the binning to be generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `cut` + `crosstab`:

```
out = (pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df['SED'], np.arange(int(df['SED'].min()), int(df['SED'].max())+1, 0.5)), df['f'])
       .add_prefix('count_').rename_axis(index='SED_bins').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
f    SED_bins  count_0  count_1
0  (0.0, 0.5]        1        1
1  (0.5, 1.0]        1        2
2  (8.0, 8.5]        0        1
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear but there could be more segments so I need it to be generic and not hard-coded to these ranges

Comment: @okuoub do we know the minimum and maximum values of `SED`?

Comment: yes lets say for simplicity I can get them as mn, mx

Comment: @okuoub edited the answer with a code that works on the sample.